# How to implement pagination correctly for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I use the ORM sequelize and the postgresql database. And I want to implement pagination.

Using the MongoDB database, pagination is performed this way.

```
module.exports.getBySprOilfieldId = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const query = {
            where: {
                spr_oilfields_id: req.params.spr_oilfields_id
            }
        }
        const sprwellplatforms = await SprWellplatforms.findAll(query)
        .skip(+req.query.offset)
        .limit(+req.query.limit)
        res.status(200).json(sprwellplatforms)
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }
}
```

But since I use the postgresql database, I have such errors.

> SprWellplatforms.findAll(...).skip is not a function
>
> SprWellplatforms.findAll(...).limit is not a function

How can they be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `offset` and `limit` values should be set on the options passed to `findAll()` as seen in the documentation for [Pagination/Limiting](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#pagination-limiting).

```
const query = {
  where: {
    spr_oilfields_id: req.params.spr_oilfields_id
  },
  offset: +req.query.offset,
  limit: +req.query.limit,
};
const sprwellplatforms = await SprWellplatforms.findAll(query)
```